# Virtualbox - "If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks."

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

This is my issue. Help me with the partition problem.

[image: VirtualBox screenshot]

Comment: 1) We can't see what you did so we can't advice further, 2) take time to read about how to install ubuntu in a vm

Comment: sure @wjandrea :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is a standard message that shows when you are ready to install Ubuntu, when system is ready to partition the drive and wipe previous stored information if any. Changes affect only the virtual disk, and not your actual hard drive or SSD.

Answer (score 3):

Well it isn't an issue. Just click Continue. Actually Linux works on ext filesystem. So it's just asking you to make the space you allocated to Ubuntu in virtualbox to ext partition and wipe the partition as well. Don't worry it will not harm your pc. All things are done virtually, i.e. without affecting your host OS (here windows, I guess).

Read more:

- [Introduction to **ext** filesystem](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/introduction-ext4-filesystem)
- [ext 4 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)